# How to disable logging in Jersey Client 2.x?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, jersey-client

I run a simple Dropwizard (1.2.0) web service in a test using a Jersey client (2.25.1) to invoke the service endpoint. For every request I get a log entry on the console, e.g:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2017:21:17:10 +0000] "GET /query?name=John+Doe+1 HTTP/1.1" 200 48 "-" "Jersey/2.25.1 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_92)" 84
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2017:21:17:10 +0000] "GET /query?name=John+Doe+2 HTTP/1.1" 200 48 "-" "Jersey/2.25.1 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_92)" 84
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2017:21:17:10 +0000] "GET /query?name=John+Doe+0 HTTP/1.1" 200 48 "-" "Jersey/2.25.1 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_92)" 84
```

I would like to disable these log entries to be printed on the console, since they are cluttering my output. I am assuming they are originating from the Jersey client? Am I wrong? So I tried to disable it, when creating my client, as such:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_CLIENT, Level.OFF);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
return client;
```

But this gives no effect - the log entries are still dumped on the console.

How do I disable these log entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are request logs printed by dropwizard server. If you just don't want them to be printed on console you can log them to a file. Add below config below `server:` property in your test yaml config file.

```
requestLog:
    timeZone: UTC
    appenders:
      - type: file
        currentLogFilename: /var/log/request.log
        threshold: ALL
```

You may also disable it by specifying no appenders as below in your test config.

```
requestLog:
   appenders: []
```

Comment: Thanks. But keep in mind to have a space in between 'appenders:' and '[]' (YML syntax)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may need to go to your main application class and find where the logger is being wired up to the Jersey environment. The line should look something like:

```
environment.jersey().register(new LoggingFeature(...));
```

Try deleting/commenting that line.